# Looking for a Digital Copy of Any Handwritten Sermon of St. John Vianney

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, saint, sermon

I am looking for a digital copy of any personally handwritten sermon of St. John Vianney.

From what I have read, I am under the impression that 80 or so are extant, but I have not been able to locate any.

There should be at least one available, as part of it has been placed on the cover of the following book:

[image]

QUESTION: Does anyone know where I might find a (preferably) digital version of at least one full-length sermon of St. John Vianney? Or, at least a paper version of it? Thank you.

REASON FOR THE REQUEST: If I can locate at least one of his full-length handwritten sermons, I could then explore the possibility of producing some gylphs in order to produce a "Curé of Ars" font for typography purposes.

Comment: archive.org is a good resource for digital books, though I'm unsure if you can find an original hand written sermons in this case

Comment: Yes, if I recall correctly, published books of his sermons that have been typeset; nothing in his handwriting though.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone has scanned his sermons' manuscripts (MSS), but [_Sermons du vénérable serviteur de Dieu Jean-Baptiste-Marie Vianney curé d'Ars (tomes 1-4)_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7385) is available online.

Comment: @Geremia Yes, thank you; but I am trying to see if I might be able to produce a typographical font that resembles his penmanship---hence the request for a digital copy of a handwritten manuscript. Nevertheless, thank you for the link. Though I already have access to the four tomes you provide, I look forward to seeing if yours has the additional sermons which were later added, and which my PDFs lack.

Comment: @mlchristians You should make a font for [St. Thomas Aquinas's _littera inintelligibilis_](http://sententiaedeo.blogspot.com/2010/05/handwriting-of-geniuses.html), too.  ([St. Hildegard's](http://scholastic.us.to/Hildegard.html) already exists.)

Comment: @Geremia Ah, yes! But one must learn his alphabet first. :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Christianity. It is a literature enquiry.